# Auto deleting columns when the field is blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a form that have multiple sections, skipping sections based upon an answer. I have then linked a Google Sheet to this Google Form to collect responses. These responses are auto filtered out into different tabs based upon one answer. Because my form have multiple sections, when it filters into the different tabs, there are blank columns. How can I get these blank columns to delete automatically when it filters into the tabs?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Please show how are the filtering into the tabs is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `query()` formula and list the columns you want to see in the `select` clause.

Alternatively, use a `filter()` wrapper to filter by *columns* rather than *rows*.